# Perfect numbers program python

Tags: python, function, perfect-numbers

I'm taking an intro course for python, and in one excercise we are to write a function where we type in a number and return bool True or False, if the number is a perfect number. Then we are to create another function that takes an upperlimit and will check every number up until that limit and if it is a perfect number, to print the perfect number. As of now my problem is with the 2nd half of this excersie, and instead of printing out the perfect number, it will print out how many there are with "True". Again the first function IS suppouse to return True or False, so I'm not sure how we can get the 2nd function to print out the actual number!

```
def perfect(num):
    x=1
    adding=0
    while x<num:
        if num % x == 0:
            adding=adding+x
        x=x+1

    if adding==num:
        #print(num)
        return (adding==num)
    else:
        return False

def perfectList(upperlimit):
    x=1
    while x<upperlimit:
        if perfect(x)==True:
            print(perfect(x))
        x=x+1
```

Comment: Your code may also be suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for further improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second function is very close.

```
def perfectList(upperlimit):
    x=1
    while x < upperlimit:
        if perfect(x)==True:
            print(x) # changed from print(perfect(x))
        x=x+1
```

you just needed to change to `print(x)` (the number) not `print(perfect(x))` , which returns whether the number is a perfect number.

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS! How did I not notice that! Thank you Daniel!

Comment: No problem Arnoald!

Cheers for the formatting edit Corgs

Answer (score 0):

```
def perfectn(x):
divisorlist = []
i=1
for i in range (1,x):
    if x % i == 0:
        divisorlist.append(i)
    i += i

print("The divisors of given number",x,"excluding itself are :", divisorlist)

sum=0
for i in range(0,len(divisorlist)):
    sum += divisorlist[i]
if sum == x:
    print("And it's a Perfect Number")
else:
    print("And it's not a perfect number")

    
perfectn(6)
```

output : The divisors of given number 6 excluding itself are : [1, 2, 3]

And it's a Perfect Number

```
perfectn(30)
```

output: The divisors of given number 30 excluding itself are : [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15]

And it's not a perfect number

Answer (score 0):

As @DanielBetteridge pointed out the redundant call to `perfect()` causing your output problem:

```
if perfect(x)==True:
    print(perfect(x))
```

Which can be simply done as:

```
def perfectList(upperlimit):
    x = 1

    while x < upperlimit:
        if perfect(x):
            print(x)

        x += 1
```

This might have happened due to you repeating your equality test pattern in `perfect()`:

```
if adding==num:
        #print(num)
        return (adding==num)
    else:
        return False
```

Which is also redundant and can be more simply written:

```
def perfect(number):
    total = 0

    x = 1

    while x < number:
        if number % x == 0:
            total += x
        x += 1

    return total == number
```

Finally, be aware that this is the wrong way to go about finding large perfect numbers as it will quickly bog down.  One faster approach, for large numbers, is to use the Lucas–Lehmer test to identify Mersenne primes and then derive the companion perfect numbers from the primes.

Answer (score 0):

simple method to check number on perfect:

```
def is_perfect(num):
    return sum(i for i in range(1, num) if num % i == 0) == num and num > 0
```